# How to uninstall Oracle 10g? I don't see any uninstall tool for this

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to uninstall Oracle 10g (on Windows 7), but I don't see any uninstall tool. How can I uninstall it?

Comment: Express Edition or Standard Edition?

Comment: Hi, now I'm in the same position - can you help me - what did you do in order to get rid of oracle 10g?

Answer (score 6):

run universal installer (you did install oracle with it)  and choose uninstall.

Comment: Hi, it's been long, but now I'm in the same situation - can you post where the universal installer should be?

Comment: I found it via the Start menu.

Answer (score 5):

```
*  Uninstall all Oracle components using the Oracle Universal Installer (OUI).
* Run regedit.exe and delete the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/ORACLE key. This contains registry entires for all Oracle products.
* Delete any references to Oracle services left behind in the following part of the registry:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/Ora*
  It should be pretty obvious which ones relate to Oracle.
* Reboot your machine.
* Delete the "C:\Oracle" directory, or whatever directory is your ORACLE_BASE.
* Delete the "C:\Program Files\Oracle" directory.
* Empty the contents of your "c:\temp" directory.
* Empty your recycle bin.
```

Comment: Not sure about C:\temp and the recycle bin but thanks for the registry key info.